# awk: line 1: syntax error at or near end of line

Tags: linux, shell

I keep getting the same error and dont know how to solve it

where $1 is the first field at registos.txt and $nr_registos is the argument that I give to the script

```
awk '$1 >= '$nr_registos'' registos.txt | sed -E 's/ /:/g' | cut -d':' -f8 > temporario2.txt
```

Comment: there's a `'` too many before `registos.txt`

Answer (score 0):

To pass a shell variable to awk, use the `-v` option:

```sh
awk -v n="$nr_registos" '$1 >= n' registos.txt | ...
```

---

Tangentially, awk can do what sed and cut do here:

```sh
awk -v n="$nr_registos" '
  $1 >= n {
    gsub(/ /, ":")
    split($0, f, ":")
    print f[8]
  }
' registos.txt
```

Y0u don't show the file contents: I question if the `gsub` and `split` are necessary -- do you have *sequences* of spaces, or are fields separated by a single space? If that's true, then

```sh
awk -v n="$nr_registos" '$1 >= n {print $8}' registos.txt
```

Comment: thank you for tthe explanaion,. it worked